Astropy: using SkyCoord object to calculate the AltAz coordinates for an object in a time range, want to get the date of max altitude
I want to find the date in which an object will be at its maximum altitude in the sky for a set location.
Given an object's right ascension and declination, an observers location and a range of dates, I can use SkyCoord to create an array of AltAz coordinates for the object, but I can't find a way to get dates for a specific (maximum) altitude.
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import AltAz
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

coord = SkyCoord('00:24:06', '-72.08127778', unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg))

observing_location = EarthLocation(lon=LONGITUDE, lat=LATITUDE)  
utc_offset = -3*u.hour 

#Create array of dates for a full year
every_day = np.arange('2024-04-12 00:00:00', '2025-04-12 00:00:00', np.timedelta64(1, 'D'), dtype='datetime64[s]')

time_range = Time(every_day) - utc_offset 
full_year_frame = AltAz(location=observing_location, obstime=time_range)

test_multiple_days = coord.transform_to(full_year_frame)

I can also check the value of the maximum altitude using:
print(test_multiple_days.alt.max())
Output:
52d39m33.63530113s
I can solve this using auxiliary numpy arrays but it doesn't feel right:
test_array = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": np.array(time_range), 
        "altitude": np.array(test_multiple_days.alt.to_string())
    }
)

#This line prints out the correct date and altitude
print(test_array[test_array['altitude'] == test_array['altitude'].max()])


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think you just want to use numpy's argmax(): Since the altitude is a subclass of numpy ndarray, it has a .argmax() method. You can then use this index to get the day of maximum altitude. In one line:
max_alt_time = time_range[test_multiple_days.alt.argmax()]

